# Ploblem including a file- Titanium

Tags: titanium

I get an error while i try to include the js file which is in the same folder. I tried cleaning my project but was of no use. 
The console says "**error loading path**". 
Please help.

```
var db={} 
Titanium.include('windows/gallery');
var displayButton= Ti.UI.createButton({ 
   title:'Display', 
   onClick:function(){ 
      db.gallery.open(); 
   }
});
```

I have used open function which opens the file. The open file works has no problem.

Comment: Can you please show the code?

Answer (score 0):

usually, we use require('files/myFile'), where :

1. Resources/files/myFile.js is the path (note that require doesn't use the .js)
2. The js file is NOT at the same level that app.js, but included in Resource folder.

So here, you should do

```
 Titanium.require('windows/gallery');
```

instead of

```
 Titanium.include('windows/gallery');
```

By the way, the previous method was Titanium.include('windows/gallery.**js**');
Note the .js at the end of the include version.

Is it a mobile or desktop version ?

Comment: var db={}
Titanium.include('windows/gallery');
var displayButton= Ti.UI.createButton({
    title:'Display',
    onClick:function(){
         db.gallery.open();
    }
  });
});


I have used open function which opens the file. The open file works has no problem.

Comment: I am sorry for the bad indentation.